# How to create an edge between 2 selected edges?

Tags: modeling

I'm a 3dsmax user, I'd like to ask how in Blender, we can "Connect Edges".

Please don't confuse it with loop subdivide (https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html).

I don't mean an entire edge loop. I'd just like to connect select edges. I've attached a simple image explaining it.

[image: A simple edge creation, between "x" selected edges]

[Connect Edges with 3DSMAX. NOT edge looping(CTRL+R)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdBgYMtmaW8)

Comment: The second answer in the duplicate looks just like the linked video.

Answer (score 5):

In Edge Mode, select the two edges you want to connect, and <kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide, (or  <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>).

If you're looking for an effect similar to the 3DS  'Pinch' and'Slide' you can get somewhere near by connecting edges as described with one cut, selecting it, and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (Offset Edge Slide) for the pinch, and an ordinary <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> for the slide, Not quite as flexible, there's an extra edge in the way.. but it's quick.

As always, it's worth checking out the options for these operators in the tool region.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the pinch\slide. It takes time to get my head wrapped around Blender's workflow.

Yea I got to get used to the information overload for Blender's UI. Thanks for the "tool region" tip.

Answer (score 3):

You can either:

**1)** use the Knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>), select the points that make up the edge that you want to create then press *Enter*

Note: you can Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> after entering the knife tool mode (After pressing <kbd>K</kbd>) to snap to the center of the edge.

**2)** as mentioned in the other answers, select two Perpendicular edges then press <kbd>W</kbd>-><kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: Does a simple question like that really require 4 screenshots?.. It can be answered in 3 words: select edges, hit w->s... I think it's better to keep it simpler.

Comment: you have a good point, i updated (simplified) my answer to make it easier to read and straight to the point;

Comment: Good tip on the the "center" option for knife cutting. I was wondering if that was possible, it definitely makes the knife tool more dependable and useful ! Thank you for that tip.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible by subdividing edges, the resulting edge will be the one you're looking for.

1. Select 2 edges sharing the same face but perpendicular to orientation of the edge you want to get (as on the first screenshot from your question).
2. Press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide*.

[image]

Note: there are Ngons as result of this operation; they might or might not be what you want to have, just beware if you're going to subdivide mesh with Subsurf or alike.

Comment: oops.. we seem to have given exactly the same answer at exactly the same time :)

Comment: Understand about the Ngons. This is just a simple example to illustrate the question. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

In the Edit Mode. Select the Top and the Bottom Edge and Press <kbd>W</kbd> and select sub-divide.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the animated gif showing it. Very helpful for new users to Blender! Love the community :)